# How to get entire news content from a news website

Tags: android, xml, rss

I am planning to make a desktop application which will have 5 regional newspapers and the user can select either of them to read it.
I need seperate colums such as Opinion,Editorial,Breaking News,Sports,etc. which means I need data of their every column.

But when I visited few papers' websites,they are just giving the headline, one line description and a link to read more as xml feed.On clicking the link the user is directed to their website.

I have seen many android applications like news Hunt ,World news,etc , which show the entire content.How do they do it?Are they using any backdoor or hack or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Jaunt Api .

The Api has easy-to-learn structure and also the code is efficient as well as fast.
You should give it a try.

Comment: I face this issue as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23269750/class-name-conflict-while-using-jaunt-with-android have u been able to run it successfully?o And if yes then what version?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use a third service like
http://import.io/ or http://www.mozenda.com

As you said apps like Flipboard, Breaking news sport etc are based on services like import.io

With this you can transform information from the web into usable data easily !

Answer (score 0):

They use an API that allows them to retrieve news (load from a server). 
For example yahoo, google, etc 
Not tested yet but it works (I'm sure) [see yahoo API](http://developer.yahoo.com/rss/)

In your case, You should write another view to display news details according to the news ID: Read their documentation carefully

Comment: What kind of API?Does it provide the content of more than one newspapers?

Answer (score 0):

Some of this app used JSON in retrieving the content from the web and pass into android app. check this [link](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/consuming-json-services-android-apps)

Answer (score 0):

Some Websites will write their own public API, which everyone can access with some HTTP header values sent. After sending HTTP request, they return the response in XML / JSON formats which you have to parse them inside your Android app and produce them on UI.

If in case they do not provide any API as such, then you need write a server side Crawler which crawls and parses the information(HTML Tagged information) from their websites and store them. Again then you need to write your own Web services(RESTful / SOAP) that send the parsed information to Android app via URL's or something.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using RSS feed.

visit [here](http://news.yahoo.com/rss/entertainment) and see page source, here you can get all news in item tags like this

`<item> 
<title>..</title>
<description>...</description> 
</item>`

where each item tag is for each news, you can fetch both title and description from there.

and you can get data from any link using HTTPPOST or HTTPGET mehods