# Class name conflict while using Jaunt with android

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, jsoup, jaunt-api

I am trying to use the [jaunt api](http://jaunt-api.com/) with android as per suggestion from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20002760/1291122) SO answer. But I get this error when I run the project:

```
Could not find class 'com.jaunt.h', referenced from method com.jaunt.UserAgent.a
```

I tried changing the order of referencing of libraries by putting jaunt0.9.6.3.jar at the top of android 4.3 platform.jar. But in that case, I get this error:

```
Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method box.a
```

Now it suggests that the class name "a" is at conflict. So what should I do to resolve this?

Has anyone experience with using jaunt with android?Anyone able to use it successfully?

Comment: This SO questino may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765910/could-not-find-class-xxx-referenced-from-method-xxx-yyy.